# Get youtube title with php script

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I would like to get the title of a youtube video in a variable, but everything I tried, didn't work. A part of the code below returns the title snippet in variable $output:

> {  "items": [   {    "snippet": {
>       "title": "Hardwell Live at Ultra Music Festival Miami 2016"    }   }  ] }

But how could I get only the title in a variable?

```
<?php


function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);


    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$response = curl_download('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=m1ssAFzaCsU&key=AIzaSyBj5GoJlQ4XzebaG6H2tp_WVuQ03JEOOss&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet');

if ($response) {

    $xml   = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $title = (string) $xml->title;
    echo $title;

} else {

    // Error handling.

                echo 'error';
}

?>
```

Comment: What 'echo $title' returns now?

Comment: It's no XML, but JSON.

Comment: It returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$output` is a JSON string, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) to parse it :

```
$output = '{ "items": [ { "snippet": { "title": "Hardwell Live at Ultra Music Festival Miami 2016" } } ] }';
$output_decoded = json_decode($output);
$title = $output_decoded->items[0]->snippet->title;
// $title is now 'Hardwell Live at Ultra Music Festival Miami 2016';
```

Adapted for your code :

```
<?php


function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);


    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$response = curl_download('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=m1ssAFzaCsU&key=AIzaSyBj5GoJlQ4XzebaG6H2tp_WVuQ03JEOOss&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet');

if ($response) {

    $response_decoded = json_decode($response);
    $title = $response_decoded->items[0]->snippet->title;
    echo $title;

} else {

    // Error handling.

                echo 'error';
}

?>
```